# how to assign unique id to SVG text element in d3 javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

Making a bar graph in d3.  I have 30+ bars, with 30+ corresponding labels on x-axis.  I would like x-axis labels to be hidden when the page loads (this is working), AND APPEAR only if user cursors over the corresponding bar (svg rect object).  To do this I am assigning an id to each rect and each text element.  When user cursors over rect, text will appear for ONLY the selected (mouseover'd) rect.

I can assign id to rects, but not for text.  Code:

```
      svg.selectAll("rect")
         .data(dataset)
         .enter()
         .append("rect")
            .attr("id", function(d){   
                return d.slug;        // slug = label downcased, this works
            });                       // each rect has unique id
```

However, similar code for my text element on x-axis doesn't assign an id?!

```
    svg.append("g")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
        .attr("id", function (d){    // inspect text element shows no ID.
           return d.slug;            // text doesn't have any id
        })
     .style("text-anchor", "end")
     .attr("opacity", 0.2);
```

How can I assign a unique id to my text elements in x-axis?  Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that no data is bound to the x axis ticks and therefore `d` is undefined -- you should actually get an error message when running your code.

In this particular case, you can use the index to get the relevant data item like so.

```
svg.append("g").call(xAxis)
   .selectAll("text")
   .attr("id", function(d, i) { return dataset[i].slug; });
```

**Note that this will only work if the number of axis ticks is the same as the number of data items.**

Comment: 100% satisfaction, thank you sir!  Fast, and on the money with the correct solution, thanks for saving me an hour or two this afternoon.